# Set Focus on input after Backbone View rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a view with a login form and I'm attempting to set the focus after the view is rendered. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
class App.Views.Login extends Backbone.View
  template: template("login")

  events:
    "click button": "login"

  render: ->
     @$el.html @template(@)
     @$el.find("#email").focus()
```

Also tried this;

```
class App.Views.Login extends Backbone.View
  template: template("login")

  events:
    "click button": "login"

  render: ->
     @$el.html(@template(@)).ready =>
       @$el.find("#email").focus()
```

Added router to show how Login is attached to the DOM:

```
class App.Routers.App extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: ->
    chrome = new Spokely.Views.Chrome el: $("#app")
    chrome.render()
    @mainEl = $("#main")

  routes:
    "": "index"
    "ad/:id": "show"
    "about": "about"
    "login": "login"
    "signup": "signup"

  login: ->
    view = new Spokely.Views.Login()
    @mainEl.html view.render().el
```

What am i missing?

Comment: I am not familiar with this syntax. Which language is it?

Comment: Coffeescript. http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: how do you attach the `Login` view to the main DOM ? can you add code how you do that?

Comment: Added the router for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that although you set the focus within the view, when you attach the login view to the main DOM, the focus is reset (it is not focused any more). Try:

```
login: ->
    view = new Spokely.Views.Login()
    @mainEl.html view.render().el    
    $("#email").focus()
```

Use Jquery to call the focus method after you have attached the `Login` view to the main DOM.  This will work for sure.

Alternatively, you can pass the '#main' as el to the Login view itself. Like:

```
login: ->
        view = new Spokely.Views.Login el: $("#main")
        view.render()
```

Then you dont need to add code to the router, your initial code should work.

Comment: Weird thing is, even after everything has rendered in this view, and I execute the above in the developer console, it still doesn't work. Any idea why that might be? Seems suspect to me.

Comment: When debugging with developer console, the focus is taken by the console window itself. So the focus is not set on the textbox.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah the above clip worked. I was just hoping to leave stuff like this out of the router since it doesn't seem to me to be its concern.

Comment: Another way how it works is if you pass the `'#main'` as `el` to the `Login` view itself. eg: `view = new Spokely.Views.Login el: $("#main")`. Then you dont need to add code to the router, your initial code should work. (If this way works for you then I can append this to the answer to help others)

Comment: Ah...nice. Yeah i like that better, b/c i feel like the focus is concern of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Post is very old, but still I would like to answer here as it might help someone. There is slightly better and easier approach. We can use onDomRefresh event to set the focus. onDomRefresh event will be called anytime the view has been rendered, shown, and then re-rendered.
we can use it as following:

```
onDomRefresh:function(){
  @$el.find("#email").focus()
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: onDomRefresh is only available for Marionette though isn't it?